# Как автоматически закрыть программу если вылетело исключение

Tags: c#, winforms, исключения

Есть программа написана на c# Form VS 2015, несколько исключений ловится и если появляется исключение программа автоматически вызывает Exit, но есть исключения которые словить не удается, как сделать так что бы при вылете любого исключения программа просто закрывалась, а не спрашивала пользователя?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для отлова необработанных исключений используется событие `AppDomain.UnhandledException`. В методе `Main` необходимо добавить обработчик этого события, примерно следующим образом:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Environment.Exit(1); // завершаем процесс
    };

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Comment: а не подскажете что означает 1 в Environment.Exit(1); ?

Comment: Это код возврата, который сообщает о том, как завершилась программа: если 0 - успешно, ненулевые - с ошибкой: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

После отлова всех "нужных" исключений попробуйте добавить такой код:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Тут нужные операторы, например закрытие программы и логирование
}
```

Этот код отловит любое исключение.

Comment: а если без try catch, ещё можно отловить??, так как я не пойму где конкретно оно возникает, по логам он про просто показывает что программа закрыта, а причины нет, в VS кроме этого есть ещё возможность просто при исключении закрыть программу?

Comment: @AndreyKalinin можете сделать как написал коллега в другом ответе. Но на "боевой" версии программы лучше такое не оставлять. Вы всегда должны знать где Ваша программа может упасть и обрабатывать эти места.

Comment: у меня программа падает когда к контроллеру нет подключения (если пропадает связь, которая не от меня зависит (специфика работы), а бабы операторы которые сидят там вообще за этим не наблюдают, и вот если связь пропадает вылетает исключение, я написал мини прогу если программа закрыта она сама её откроет, а если открыта ждет пока пропадает процесс, но как раз если вылетает исключение он просит Продолжить или Выйти, а мне как раз надо избегать этого окна, так что выше то что надо

Comment: @AndreyKalinin: Ну так не закрывайте процесс молча, а найдите, в чём дело и где вылетает. Баги нужно фиксить.

Comment: фиксить можно покупкой дорогостоющего оборудования Контроллер много модулей, новый ОПС сервер и Езернет кабель, а не старенькое барахло работающее по ком порту не стабильно :( так что фиксить буду тогда когда завод решит денег дать на это